# How do i find out the URL of my official Google+ page?

Tags: google, google-plus, google-plus-pages

I've created a Google Plus site for one of our group of companies.  However, Google says "Google has suspended your page due to quality issues". The problem is Google will not show the updated contact details until I've filled in a request page. The page is Google My Business local business reinstatement request" and one of the questions while filling the form in is "What is the URL of your official Google+ page?"

I've typed the address I think it should be and clicked ok but Google highlights the question to say it's not correct.  How do I find out what this address is?

Here's the address I think it should be https://plus.google.com/111385540284422630209/

Comment: That loads fine for me, showing S C G Solutions. Is that not right?

Comment: No, google does not accept it as the correct url. should it be a name instead of numbers? such as  https://plus.google.com/scg solutions/

Comment: @resolver101 name is a vanity URL that i think only comes when you verify the address *page*. All pages still have the numbers too by default and should still work

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a second, very similar g+ page, I found this by searching for the company's name and address and restricting the search to plus.google.com

http://plus.google.com/116517652696883112626/

It seems that google may have picked up that both pages had the same address, website name, etc, and suspended the newer one as a result. Neither page has officially been linked to the company's website, which is an important next step and should allow you to claim the custom 'vanity URL' [instructions](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4569085?hl=en-GB)

If you are using a Local Business page instead [this process](https://support.google.com/business/answer/2911778?vid=1-635761920115266015-21970129) needs to be followed instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasnt manager of this "2nd" account so requested management and waiting for verification codes to come through.  I will then delete this 2nd page and hopefully this will release the the other page.  Thanks and i'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 1):

Hah its not your fault. Pardon the rant in this questions but Google+ is a confusing mess. For as much as they try to make this a keystone, and get people on it, G+ is far too fragmented and confusing for most who use it. Regardless, here is what i think might be wrong:

So the link you provided seems to highlight "profile" within the dropdown on the left side of the screen. This is hinting to me that it is not a page at all; rather its the *profile* assimilated to either A) legacy G+ entities before the migrate, or B) a non-location-based account designed for personal users...aka humans. This account could be summarized as *"An owner of a property, for which the property has a page, for which the page is actually a Google local entity"* So you are looking at an account designed to be used by a human, not your biz. Example, a profile like yours:

Fig-0
[image: this is not a page, it's a human profile not intended for a biz or location]

This might be an old G+ styled profile that needs migrated/merged, or it could be a real profile. We will never know. Regardless, here is what an actual business location page looks like:

Fig-1
[image: Correct places for business page]

What you need to do is visit https://www.google.com/business/ and log in using the *owner/master account* in order to see (or add) business locations. Ironically, this will drop you into plus.google.com and expose the business functions and dropdown menu item. Another alternative is to log into G+ with that same owner/master and click "pages" in the side nav, then "create new page". This will drop you, confusingly, into a different subdomain than the previous method uses. Either way you need to be in pages, on the owner/master account. If the business(s) is/are there, you will see something like this:

Fig-2
[image: list of biz pages]

**^^ So, if it exists, click one of the properties above (Fig-2) and skip to Fig-5 to view the profile**

If there is nothing there, click the "get my page" and you will be presented with this wizard, which you must complete using the owner/master account, then address verify using postcards or something:

Fig-3
[image: how to make a biz page with wizard]

After you complete and verify, you should see business card listed like in Fig-2. Now since you are on the owner/master account there is a trick to view it....or you may want to add manager users (like yourself) on other accounts. To do either you click the blue button called "Manage this page" on the card from Fig-2. This is where you find page settings and the ability to actually view the page:

Fig-4
[image: How to get to page view or settings]

Once you are in manage page, choose your own adventure. You can either A) view the page from the side nav dropdown, or B) find the gear in the corner and manage settings/users.

Fig-5 - solves A)
[image: how to get to the public facing page]
**^^ Clicking this link within a page management window should get you the correct biz page URL.** Or perhaps you want to also add yourself, a human, as manager to be able to see the property and subsequent link in the future:

Fig-6 - solves B)
[image: how to add yourself/others as managers so you dont have to use master account]

Followed by clicking the managers tab. Verify with the email link and you're safe to logout of owner/master and into your normal employee/personalized G account. G should now accept your mitigations/verifications as something from the company, rather than an "outsider" or whatever trying to work a non-logistical profile.

Fig-7
[image: managing the management of managers]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed post.  I am the manager of the page and i've already applied/received the google my business verification and its been accepted.  i still cant figure out how to get the URL that google is looking for. google has made this one frustrating.  Any other advice to get this thing working?